# Integral of a binomial with non-integer exponent

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to find a closed form or at least get a fair approximation (with a series expansion) of the following integral:

$$\int \left( Ax+\frac{B}{x} \right)^{1/n}\,dx$$

Where $n$ is any integer and $A$ and $B$ are constants. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, it turns out that this integral involves the hypergeometric function $_2F_1$. That means it cannot be represented as a fixed number of elementary functions. I think you will have to settle for the series expansion, if it is tractable.